# Method for Extracting application name from SQL Server Audit log or SQL Audit trace?

Tags: sql-server, event-log, syslog

I have two sample SQL Server 2012 and 2014 instances, and a central syslog server, I'm searching the web since weeks but cannot find a solution.

I would like to exctract the "application name" field or any similar from a relevant source, Audit log or audit trace. I've found the needed field in the .trc file, but nothing in Audit logs and also cannot find a method how to write this kind of log to a readable text file (in order to forward it to a syslog server).

It would be good to know the client application name (eg.: SQL Server Management Studio) or process name (pymssql) that's using database resources, connects do queries... etc.

Has somebody already faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> cannot find a method how to write this kind of log to a readable text file (in order to forward it to a syslog server).

```
SELECT  TE.name AS [EventName] ,
        T.DatabaseName ,
        t.DatabaseID ,
        t.NTDomainName ,
        t.ApplicationName ,
        t.LoginName ,
        t.SPID ,
        t.Duration ,
        t.StartTime ,
        t.EndTime
FROM    sys.fn_trace_gettable(CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                              f.[value]
                                                      FROM    sys.fn_trace_getinfo(NULL) f
                                                      WHERE   f.property = 2
                                                    )), DEFAULT) T
        JOIN sys.trace_events TE ON T.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id
WHERE   te.name = 'Data File Auto Grow'
        OR te.name = 'Data File Auto Shrink'
ORDER BY t.StartTime ;
```

More Examples :

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server-the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/collecting-the-information-in-the-default-trace/

Comment: I believe the ApplicationName will only be filled when the entry "Application name=value" is present in the connectionstring of the clients. But I am not sure